# Extract only a part of data from a file

Tags: bash, sed, grep

My input is test.txt which contains data in this format:

```
'X'=>'ABCDEF',
'X'=>'XYZ',
'X'=>'GHIJKLMN',
```

I want to get something like:

```
'ABCDEF',
'XYZ',
'GHIJKLMN',
```

How do I go about this in bash?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you include what you've already tried?

Answer (score 1):

If the input never contains the character `>` elsewhere than in the "fat arrow", you can use `cut`:

```
cut -f2 -d\> file
```

- `-d` specifies the delimiter, here `>` (backslash needed to prevent the shell from interpreting it as the redirection operator)
- `-f` specifies which field to extract

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using sed:

```
curl -sL https://git.io/fjeX4 | sed 's/^.*>//'
```

Sed is passed a single command:  s///.    is a regex that matches any characters  (.*) from the beginning of the line (^)  to the last '>'.   The  is an empty string, so essentially sed is just deleting all the characters on the line up to the last >.  As with the other solutions, this solution assumes that there is only one '>' on the line.

Answer (score 0):

If the data is really uniform, then you could just run [cut](https://linux.die.net/man/1/cut) (on [example input](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/miku/612c7cae1fb1e20d7e3d2f314e423541/raw/d8dc235c4637263ca6b4b3ef2fab99b97c68732c/in.txt)):

```
$ curl -sL https://git.io/fjeX4 | cut -d '>' -f 2
'ABCDEF',
'XYZ',
'GHIJKLMN',
```

You can see flag explanations on [explainshell](https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=curl+-sL+https%3A%2F%2Fgit.io%2FfjeX4+%7C+cut+-d+%27%3E%27+-f+2).

With [awk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK), it would look similar:

```
$ curl -sL https://git.io/fjeX4 | awk -F '>' '{ print $2 }'
'ABCDEF',
'XYZ',
'GHIJKLMN',
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="=>"}{print $2}' file
'ABCDEF',
'XYZ',
'GHIJKLMN',
```

`FS` in awk stands for field separator. The code inside `BEGIN` is executed only at the beginning, ie, before processing the first record. `$2` prints the second field.

A more idiomatic way of putting the above stuff would be

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="=>"}$2' file
'ABCDEF',
'XYZ',
'GHIJKLMN',
```

The default action in `awk` is to print the record. Here we explicitly mention what to print. ie `$2`.